# Loop function from a certain row till the last row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of urls in column A, and I'm copying and pasting formulas from a row that contains the formulas (Template row) against the URLs to extract data.
The code then does a SpreadsheetApp.flush(); and then copies the the results from that particular row and pastes it as values onto the same row.

[image]

The code I've put together to do this is as follows.

```
function scraper(){
  copypasteFormulas();
  copypasteResultValues();
}

function copypasteFormulas() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");


 var sourceRange = sheet.getRange('B2:T2'); //Copy formulas from template row
 var sourceFormulas = sourceRange.getFormulasR1C1();

 var targetRange = sheet.getRange('B5:T5'); //Paste formulas 
  targetRange.setFormulasR1C1(sourceFormulas);

}

function copypasteResultValues() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

 SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //Delay between paste of formula and copypaste of values onto it's self

 var copyFromRange = 'Sheet1!B5:T5'; // Copies result range
 var copyToRangeStart = 'Sheet1!B5'; // Pastes results into itself as values
 var source = sheet.getRange(copyFromRange);
  source.copyTo(sheet.getRange(copyToRangeStart), {contentsOnly: true});

}
```

However I'd like for this to loop through every row till the last row and  start again from B5:T5 to the end of the rows.

For example the following stays constant since thats where the formulas are copied from.

```
 var sourceRange = sheet.getRange('B2:T2'); //Copy formulas from template row
 var sourceFormulas = sourceRange.getFormulasR1C1();
```

The rest needs to change as each row gets filled in

```
 var targetRange = sheet.getRange('B5:T5'); //Paste formulas 
  targetRange.setFormulasR1C1(sourceFormulas);

 var copyFromRange = 'Scraper!B5:T5'; // Copies result range
 var copyToRangeStart = 'Scraper!B5'; // Pastes results into itself as values
```

I'm not sure how to do this.

> ****** **UPDATE** ******

I managed to put together the following code to loop through from a certain row to the last row.

```
function iterativeCopyPaste() {
  // Get array of values in the search Range
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Scraper");
 var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
 var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
 var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
 var searchRange = sheet.getRange(2,2, lastRow-1, lastColumn-1);
 var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues(); // Loop through array and if condition met, add relevant
  
 var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(2,2,1,19); //Copy formulas from template row
 var sourceFormulas = sourceRange.getFormulasR1C1();
 
// Copy paste formulas and copy paste result to values iteration
 for ( j = 5 ; j < lastRow - 1; j++){
      var i = 2;
      if(rangeValues[j][i] === ""){
        var targetRange = sheet.getRange(j, i, 1, 19); //row range to which the formulas are pasted
        targetRange.setFormulasR1C1(sourceFormulas);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    };
      var source = sheet.getRange(j, i, 1, 19); // result range to copy
       SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        source.copyTo(sheet.getRange(j, i, 1, 19), {contentsOnly: true}); // Pastes results into itself as values
       SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  };

};
```

However it stops two rows before the last row, so I had to add two dummy rows at the end of the list on column A so the urls get looped through.

The formulas that get copied into the rows use importxml to extract data and sometimes they get stuck on "Loading", one of the formulas I use as follows.

```
=if(iserror(IMPORTXML($A2,"//h1[contains(@class,'ch-title')]")),"Loading",IMPORTXML($A2,"//h1[contains(@class,'ch-title')]"))
```

Is there any way that the iteration only goes ahead only if none of the cells in `sheet.getRange(j, i, 1, 19)` show as loading.

EDIT: It appears that if I use a

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
Utilities.sleep(100000);
```

under *//row range to which the formulas are pasted* it appears to slowly go through all the URLs loading up all the data and then copying and pasting on itself as values. So far it seems to work well.

Comment: `B5:T7` is not a row (it's a range in 3 rows). So I'm not sure what you mean by iterating each row the the end of the rows. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, it's not B5:T7 but B5:T5. And what I mean by that the function run from row to row is, for example, it first runs from B5:T5 then it runs from B6:T6 and so on till the last row of urls in column A. I hope that helps.

Comment: There are two issues with your approach. 1) The maximum allowed value for the [sleep](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer)) function is `300000` milliseconds, therefore you can't have `14400000`. 2) `300000` milliseconds is equal to 5 minutes but you can only run your script for 30 minutes. Namely, if you put that code in an iteration, you can only run it for 6 rows.. You can use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` instead which is supposed to update the pending changes in the sheet and it won't take that much time.

Comment: If `flush` is working, then you can set up a loop I guess but it depends how much time does it take for your formulas to be updated.

Comment: The formulas use importxml so I gave it about 1.5-2 mins to update to get the necessary data before its copied and pasted onto itself as a value. So in that way the importxml doesn't case limitations. So does it mean that 300000 milliseconds is the limit per use or totally the number of times its used should equal 300000 milliseconds

Comment: the flush appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code I put together that works for what I wanted.
And set a time trigger to run every 30 minutes incase there is a timeout.

```
   function iterativeCopyPaste() {
  // Get array of values in the search Range
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Scraper");
  var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
  var searchRange = sheet.getRange(2,2, lastRow-1, lastColumn-1);
 var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues(); // Loop through array and if condition met, add relevant
 
 var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(2,2,1,10); //Copy formulas from template row
 var sourceFormulas = sourceRange.getFormulasR1C1();
 var counter = 0;
 

// Copy paste formulas and copy paste result to values iteration
for ( j = 5 ; j < lastRow - 1; j++){
        var i = 2;
    counter++;
    var targetRange = sheet.getRange(j, i, 1, 10); //row range to which the formulas are pasted
        if(targetRange.isBlank()){
        //var targetRange = sheet.getRange(j, i, 1, 10); //row range to which the formulas are pasted
        targetRange.setFormulasR1C1(sourceFormulas);
        
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        Utilities.sleep(100000); // Delay before the copy and paste of result values
    };
      var source = sheet.getRange(j, i, 1, 19); // result range to copy
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        source.copyTo(sheet.getRange(j, i, 1, 19), {contentsOnly: true}); // Pastes results into itself as values
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        if (counter === 4) {    // Delay after every 5 rows
            Utilities.sleep(240000);
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
          counter = 0;
        };
};

};
```